# How can I overwrite an unmanaged solution when using deploying a CRM package?

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Using [a powershell script to deploy a CRM Package](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn647420.aspx) works well, but I am running into some unexpected behavior.

The package has 1 unmanaged solution that it uploads. It works perfectly if the solution does not exist on the target CRM organization. However, if the solution does already exist on the organization and I try to deploy it again with some changes, it will not work. The changes are not uploaded and I do not get any errors.

If I change the version number in the solution (from 0.0.1 to 0.0.2, for example) then uploading it works as expected.

I would rather not change the version every time though, and since manually uploading an unmanaged solution with the same version number works perfectly I would expect the script to be able to do it as well.

Comment: Did you publish the solution after importing it?  how could you verify that the solution didn't upload otherwise/what do you mean when you say "it will not work"?

Comment: For example if I add another entity to the solution, export it, then import it into a different organization, that entity does not show up in the newly imported solution. I verify this by opening the solution in CRM to see what components it contains.

And, I did try publishing, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried using the [CRM Package Deployer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn647420.aspx) method of importing a package to see if it would work as I expect or if it would show any error messages.

It's messages show:

`Skipping solution MySolution. Version 0.0.2 of the solution is already loaded.`

So it appears that if a solution with the same name and version number exists in the organization then it will be skipped entirely. This is sort of unfortunate.

It seems I'll have to implement a workaround. I see two options:

1. The DeployPackage script deletes the solution in the target CRM organization (if it exists) before attempting to upload.
2. My ExportSolution script changes the version number every time it runs.

Comment: Good to know, I haven't tried this.  To be fair, the version number probably should be incremented before loading the same solution into an environment.  I have begun using the date as the version number (plus the actual version on this particular day) and it seems to work great and makes auditing/tracking changes easier than a more traditional major.minor.revision.buildnumber - ie my first solution today would be 2015.09.16.1